# Why are my remote ships being attacked by seemingly neutral Terran ships in war (red on the map) sectors?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I have a great reputation with Terrans, though I have at one point damaged my reputation with them nearly beyond repair. Now, I quite often see my ships being attacked by Terran ships in war (shown as red on the Universe map) sectors, and whenever I open the sector map via the attacked ship's menu, I see a red, hostile Terran ship. When I enter the sector, no hostile Terrans are to be seen. Sometimes my ship manages to destroy the attacker, leading to reputation loss for me, sometimes it gets destroyed, which is even worse. It almost seems the AI has become quite a bit smarter and more vindictive, but that is implausible. What's the reason behind these sneak attacks on my property?

When I'm looking at the map while out of sector, entering the ship's information menu turns it blue for several seconds until it reverts to red. I've managed to track one of those red Terrans by its registration number and the captain was perfectly cordial with me. Sometimes the attacking ships will be blue on approach, but turn red as soon as they engage my ship; though after I jump in they turn blue again.

Even my satellites are getting destroyed by them, despite there being no way for the Terrans to track them - they are well above any ship activity at Y:50km, and the Springblossom laying the satellites is far too fast for the Terran ships to chase it until the satellite comes in range of their scanners.

Comment: are you sure your current ship doesn't have terrans set as friendly no matter what?

Comment: @spartacus good point, but no, all my ships have "Show as enemy if enemy to me" set to "Yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

War sectors have special scripted behaviour:

If you're out-of-sector, then war ships will attack your property (ship, station, satellite, laser tower) regardless of your relationship with their race or position in sector.

If you're in-sector, friendly warships will not attack.

You can forbid your Universe Traders from trading in these sectors using the **MK3 Blacklist Manager** under Additional Ship Commands (thought they will still pass through these sectors if they provide the best path to stations in sectors without jumpgates/beacons).

The Shady Business plot provides an opportunity to put an end to the Argon-Terran war and, consequently, these unprovoked attacks.

Comment: +1 that's the only thing i cna think of, war sector behavior is a little strange.

Comment: I've added some information about how to deal with the issue to your answer. Feel free to delete these changes if you feel they detract from your answer.

Comment: Your changes is correct, you just did not asked how to stop attacks :)